# when i am converting list of dicts to dataframe i am getting different format of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am converting list of dictionaries to data frame to store in database but I am not getting proper format of data frame

my_list=[{'A': '1111', 'B': '2222', 'C': '3333'}, {'A': '4444', 'B': '5555', 'C': '6666'}]

[This is the dataframe format i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTkuS.png)

[This is the dataframe i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zXt.png)

The code i am using

```
df=pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange I ran your code as-is and got the result you want.

Comment: I just used your code and if I print df, I get the result you are looking for...

Comment: @0x0fba yeah that line of code correct and it is working fine. i dont know why in my code its not working... Is there any conditions that can effect my dataframe sturucture

Comment: Just based on this extract it'll be difficult to have better answers. Do you have a lot of code between `my_list` init and the dataframe creation ? Is there any chance that `my_list` has been modified ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_list)
```